# How to close mic for a conversation action?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Google just rejected my app that I'd built using API AI. Following is the feedback from Google team:

*Please either close the mic after app delivers its functionality, or prompt the user to either ask again or cancel.*

Does anyone know how to prompt the user/ask again/cancel?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With API.AI, there are a few options:

1. If you are not using a webhook for the intent, check the *End Conversation* box in the *Actions on Google* section at the bottom of the intent page.
2. If you are using a webhook with the ApiAiAssistant Javascript library, you can use the `assistant.tell()` method instead of the `assistant.ask()` method. (See https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ApiAiAssistant#tell for details.)  (**Update**: These are now `conv.add()` and `conv.close()` in [version 2 of the library](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview). And API.AI is now called "Dialogflow".)
3. If you're sending back raw JSON responses from your webhook, you need to set the `data.google.expect_user_response` property to `false` to end the conversation. (See https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/webhook-format#response for details about the JSON response.)

Answer (score 0):

To end the conversation you can either use the client library "tell" method in fulfillment or you can use the "End conversation" Actions on Google option at the bottom of the intent settings in API.AI.

Comment: Is the client library available in Java?

Comment: The client library from Google is currently for Node.js.

Comment: @Sai - there is now a Java client library. See https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/java/overview

Answer (score -3):

You can simply say "Set this as the End of Conversation" which is already present below ADD Response Button during your intent building process!!